# How do I find the minimal number of pings to test a network's route table?

Tags: ping

After configuring a network, how can I test that my routers are configured correctly with the minimal number of pings?

Is there an appropriate traversal for finding this?

Example problem:
[image: Example problem]

Comment: Unfortunately, all "education, certification, or homework_" questions are explcictly off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

From Host 1 you can ping to Host 3, Host 5, and Host 6.  This way a ping will traverse all of your subnets.